# Error: "Expected ',' but got 'memory'" in Nodejs/truffle console when trying to compile

Tags: truffle-compile

```
CompileError: /C/Users/Asusupernova/Downloads/TrufflePart2/contracts/Hello.sol:8:30: ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'memory'
    constructor(string _name memory) public {
                             ^----^
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity^0.5.16;

contract HelloWorld {
    string private name;

    constructor(string _name memory) public {
      name = _name;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
      return name;
    }

    function setName(string _name) public {
      name = _name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memory` access specifier is in the wrong place. It should be after the type and before the argument name

```
constructor(string memory _name) {
```